Removing the default variation alert with inline alert message in Woocommerce
I'm trying to remove the default variation popup alert message with an inline alert instead in Woocommerce.
in the (class-wc-fronted-script.php) here is the code I have:
case 'wc-add-to-cart-variation':
// We also need the wp.template for this script :).
wc_get_template( 'single-product/add-to-cart/variation.php' );

$params = array(
    'wc_ajax_url'                      => WC_AJAX::get_endpoint( '%%endpoint%%' ),
    'i18n_no_matching_variations_text' => esc_attr__( 'Sorry, no products matched your selection. Please choose a different combination.', 'woocommerce' ),
    'i18n_make_a_selection_text'       => esc_attr__( 'Please select some product options before adding this product to your cart.', 'woocommerce' ),
    'i18n_unavailable_text'            => esc_attr__( 'Sorry, this product is unavailable. Please choose a different combination.', 'woocommerce' ),
);
break;


Any suggestions?
Thanks!
I tried this function:
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', function () {
    // Remove WooCommerce's add-to-cart variation script
    wp_dequeue_script('wc-add-to-cart-variation');
}, 100);


but with no luck

You need to look to line 634 to where it uses woocommerce_get_script_data
